# Compiling web components with TypeScript and webpack doesn't work

Tags: typescript, webpack, web-component, custom-element

I’m trying to compile my custom element on the browser but im getting this error.

i was able to run this code successfully in storybook but for some reason the same code doesn't work on the browser.

[image: The error in the browser]

tsconfig.json:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/index.ts"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: "css-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "script.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "static", "bundle"),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

now its working!

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "es6" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */,
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  }
}
```

packge.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/main.ts",
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  },
};
```